# An event happens on business day $k$ of the month -- what does this mean?

Tags: probability

I'm going through an interview prep book for probabilities, and there is a question that states

> An event happens on business day $k$ of the month. We want the minimize the number of times it happens on a Monday. What $k$ do we choose? (We prefer smaller $k$ if equal probability).

What does business day $k$ of the month mean? The $k$-th business day of the month?

Comment: Yes, I would read it that way.

Comment: @lulu Strictly, we would only need to consider $k \leq 7$ right since we cycle through a 7 day week?

Comment: I'm not sure of that.  The weekends get tricky.  Also:  i assume we are meant to ignore Holidays?   Are we also meant to ignore the probability of the the day of the week on which Calendar $1$ appears?

Comment: @lulu Yeah, I think we ignore holidays. Or at least that's what I'm going to do. If we assume that there are 12 months and exactly 28 days each month (for simplicity), then I think $k = 4,5,6$ are all equally valid. The only time where there would be an event on Monday is if the first of the month was Thursday, Wednesday, Tuesday, respectively. If if we assume all 7 days of the week can occur with equal probability on the first day of the month, this would give us a 1/7 probability that there will be a meeting on Monday if we choose k=4,5 or 6.

Comment: For instance:  If $Cal_1$ is on a Monday then of course $B_1$ is a Monday.   What's $B_8$?  Well, $B_2=Tues, B_3=Wed, B_4=Th, B_5=Fri, B_6=Mon, B_7=Tues$ so $B_8=Wed$.

Comment: @lulu What is Calendar 1?

Comment: I'm using $Cal_i$ to denote the $i^{th}$ day of the month, ignoring Business days.

Comment: @lulu Actually, when I think about it, I think my above approach even if we're using a regular calendar. I looked at historical averages, and the first day of the month is pretty evenly distributed across the 7 days of the week.

Comment: That is *exactly* what it means: The $k$-th business day of the month.  .... It's a weird question a given year will have more $k$-th business days on some days than others but it will change every year and after 28 years will even out.  Are we suppose to minimize for a specific year? Which year? Or in general? For how long. There is nothing about the business schedule.  Why should we assume they work Mon to Fri? And can we cheat and say $k = 32$ so it *never* happens.  Or $k=23$ (or whatever) so is only sometimes happens? What if we declare "all employees take monday off!"

Comment: @fleablood I think we just consider what has occurred historically and what will occur indefinitely in the future, so we're not bounded to a range of years or a specific year. We assume people work M-F. I don't think we can cheat. I think we can only consider $k \leq 31$, though I think we actually only need to consider $k \leq 5$.

Comment: "I looked at historical averages, and the first day of the month is pretty evenly distributed across the 7 days of the week. "  Actually it *isn't* but it differs year by you and will eventually even out.  To answer this you *need* a time frame.  But if you say that it is specifically in 2021 for example: Sunday, Tues, Saturday occur 1 time, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday occur twice, and Monday 3 times.  But next year will be completely different.

Comment: "I think we just consider what has occurred historically and what will occur indefinitely in the future, so we're not bounded to a range of years or a specific year. "  Well, then that is just nutty.  A month is just as likely to begin on one day as it is on any other.  (I kind of assumed everybody knew that....)  After all a year has $365=52\cdot 7 + 1$ day say if month begins on one day, in a year it will begin on the next and every day will occur equally often.  (Yes, even leap years and centuries will even out through a lowest common multiple)

Comment: If the $k-th$ day of month $J$ is a Monday on one year, then it will be a Tuesday the year after that and so on.  Even if we take leap years into account, in $28$ years *every* day will have occurred exactly $4$ times. Every day will be the $k$ th day of a month equally often eventually unless you have some time frame.

Comment: Can you actually give the actual problem in *all* details?  It seems to me to be a meaningless question in general but for a specific year a very practical question.

Comment: @fleablood That is the actual problem verbatim. I don't think you're supposed to consider a specific time frame, and I think you are supposed to assume that a month is just as likely to begin on one day as it is on any other. So $k=4,5,6$ would all minimize the number of events on a Monday.

Comment: Well, then it's a stupid problem! The $k$th day is equally likely to be any day of the week so choose $k=1$.  I mean, it *is* completely and totally obvious the $k$th day is equally likely to be any day, isn't it?

Comment: @fleablood No. If you choose $k = 1$, then if the first of the month is Saturday, Sunday, or Monday, then the first business day of the month is Monday. So for $k = 1$, there's a 3/7 probability that the first business day is a Monday.